# How does the 72 hour limit mentioned in the AUP affect suspensions?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, account-suspension, legal

I just came across the [Acceptable Usage Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)

There's a bit in there that goes

> If you are found to be in violation of any of the below policies, you will receive a notice via email. Unless you explain or correct your behavior within 72 hours, your account will be suspended. We will do our best to work with you and ensure a fair outcome in all cases. We reserve the right to immediately suspend, without notice, any content, account, or IP address which we determine to be submitting spam or other potentially damaging or disruptive content to the Network.

Everything listed there's probably an immediate suspension or even account deletion worthy offense

As a moderator, or even a regular user - how does this 72 hour "notice" period affect how we deal with these policies and suspensions in general?

Comment: Is this clause even used? I think I understand it the way you do - that (nearly) anything that is worthy of a suspension is worthy of an *immediate* suspension, and that anything that's minor enough that it makes sense to give someone 72 hours to fix it before taking action wasn't ever suspension-worthy to begin with.

Comment: That's what I was wondering too

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. "You have 72 hours to stop posting questions that are nothing but dick picks or we'll suspend your account." "You have 72 hours to stop spamming for dietary supplements or we'll *really* suspend your account."

Comment: Well... I'll probably nuke those and let the CM team deal with trolls and spammers who are also rules lawyers lol.